# Is $x^2$ analytic in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

The question is as is, just proving that $x^2$ is analytic in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this just true because for $|x|<1$ we have by the geometric series that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^2 = \frac{1}{1-x}$. If we can rewrite it like this, isn't it clearly analytic, or is there more going on here.

Comment: Can you find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $x^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$?

Comment: Isn't $x^2$ a polynomial and hence a power series? What is your definition of an analytic function?

Comment: It's analytic because $x^2$ is itself a power series. Note that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx^k$ can have all the $a_k=0$ if you like.

Comment: So if we can represent $x^2$ as a power series, then its analytic? Theres a lengthy definition in the book, but It was hard to get that from it.

Comment: @Logan What is that lengthy definition? Without knowing it all I can say is that yes, $x^2$ itself is a power series everywhere, hence analytic.

Comment: The definition is as follows : A real valued function $f$ is said to be real analytic on a nonempty, open interval $(a,b)$ if and only if given $x_o$ $\in$ $(a,b)$ there is a power series centered at $x_o$ which converges to f near $x_o$; that is, if and only if there exist coefficients ${a_k}$ from $k=0$ to infinity and points $c,d$ $\in$ $(a,b)$ such that $c<x_o<d$ and $f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k(x-x_o)^k$ for all $x$ $\in$ (c,d).

Comment: So yeah, set $x_0=0$, set $a_0=a_1=a_3=a_3=a_4=...=0$, and set $a_2=1$. Although I suppose that by that definition you also need to do it for other values of $x_$....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such coefficients exist : given $x_0$, note that $f(x_0+a) = (x_0 + a)^2 = x_0^2 + 2ax_0+a^2$.

Therefore, the power series around $x_0$ converging to $f$ near $x_0$, would just be given by $f(y) = (y-x_0)^2 + 2x_0(y-x_0) + x_0^2$ i.e. $a_0 = x_0^2, a_1 = 2x_0,a_2 = 1$ and the rest being $0$. Note that $c,d$ can be taken as large as you want : in fact, this power series converges *everywhere* because it is a polynomial.

A power series is a generalization of a polynomial. In particular, any polynomial will definitely be analytic.